# Cannot always start debugging on VS 2010 with VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I cannot start the debugger in VS 2010 under Windows 10. I've been using VS2010 for many years now but just recently moved to a new dev box under Windows 10. This just started a few days ago. Prior to that I as able to launch the debugger without issue.

I can start without debugging <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> but <kbd>F5</kbd> or clicking the green start arrow will not work. I can see the development web server open and there's a flash of the screen but IE never opens and the app returns to the "stopped" state within a few seconds.

I've been looking through all of the suggested options but nothing I have tried has worked so far. The other day I got it working by doing a clean and then rebuild all, but that hasn't worked today.

Comment: Update! I made some code changes and then without thinking hit the green arrow to start debugging. The app loaded in IE in debugging mode. Weird! I'd love to know why, but at least it's working.

Comment: Another update. Some times a clean and then rebuild all works, sometimes not. Some times making a minor change to the source code works and sometimes it does not. I wish I could find a solution to this. Very frustrating. Is anyone listening or is this a Monologue!!